# Infimum and supremum And Net

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory, nets

We know that every **Partially Ordered Set** has to satisfy three conditions :

1. Reflexive
2. Anti-Symmetric
3. Transitive

If we have the partially ordered set $S$ with a relation $R$, and $S$ also satisfies the following two conditions: For any two elements $a$ and $b$ such that  $a \subseteq S$ and  $b \subseteq S$:

1. there is always $m \subseteq S$
   where $m$ is equal to $\inf\,\{a,b\}$;   (the infimum of $a$ and $b$),
2. and also there will be  $n \subseteq S$
   where $n$ is equal to $\sup\,\{a,b\}$;   (the supremum of $a$ and $b$)

In this case, does the set $S$ has a special name?
Is it possible to define a **net** on this set?
I know my question is so silly but I am beginner in this field.

I also want to ask if we have  a **net** $N$ has been defined on a partially ordered set $S$ that satisfies the previous conditions (1, 2) **AND** also: Every **subset** of $S$ also satisfies the same conditions (1, 2), in this case, 
what can we call The **net** $N$?
Any help will mean a lot.

Comment: @amrsa Can you help me bro?

Comment: S is a lattice and nets can be defined with it.

Comment: When you write @some_user, that some_user is notified of your comment if he has comment that same question or answer. So I was not notified. Meanwhile I came across this just because I saw the question. Of course William Elliot already gave you the answer (though I don't know anything about nets): it's a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order))

Comment: @WilliamElliot thanks a lot 
just  if you can give a help with the last question  " if we have A **Net** $N$ has been defined on A Partial Order Set $S$ that satisfy the previous Conditions($1,2$) **AND** also: Every **Subset** Of $S$ Also satisfy the Same Conditions ($1,2$), In This Case What Can we Call The **Net** $N$?"

Comment: @amrsa thanks alot for your clarification :)